# Creating viewmodels out of inheritance tree

Tags: c#, design, inheritance

I have a domain interface `ITransformation` with several implementing classes such as `RemoveRowsTransformation` and `AddColumnTransformation`. The inheritance tree models the command pattern. The `ITransformation` interface defines an `Execute(table)`. Each implementing class contains different properties it needs to implement the method. For example:

```
public class RemoveRowsTransformation : ITranformation {
    public int TopRowsCount { get; private set; }
    public int BottomRowsCount { get; private set; }
    //snip
}

public class AddColumnTransformation : ITranformation {
    public string ColumnName { get; private set; }
    //snip
}
```

Various domain methods either require or create an `IEnumerable<ITransformation>`. This enumerable has to be presented in the view (sent as JSON over web API, specifically) for viewing and editing. How to most efficiently present the data in the enumerable of transformations (inheritance tree) in the view or elsewhere?

Currently, each concrete transformation is creating a viewmodel. This doesn't sit well with me, because this way the domain is tied to the view layer. Also, if a different view is necessary or a different model is used for saving the data into database, a specific method in the domain will have to be made for each conversion.

An alternative approach I've used is to create an interface which particular models will inherit and domain models filling those interfaces. This seems cleaner, but still leads to a large, unmanageable amount of `IDomainClassModel` and implementations for every single thing imaginable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you injected a dictionary into your view that maps from a concrete type of `ITransformation` to the appropriate transformation view? You can iterate over your `IEnumerable<ITransformation>`, call `GetType()` on each and instantiate the correct view for each using the dictionary.

There are a number of benefits to this approach:

- Domain isn't coupled to presentation layer
- Can optionally reuse the same view for multiple concrete implementations of `ITransformation` without duplicate code or messy design
- Can specify different dictionaries depending on context (edit vs view, summary view, detailed view, focused view, etc.)

Comment: I like having static typing, but I guess there's no proper way to have my cake and eat it too this time.